# How can I highlight the dates in month calender control?

Tags: c#, .net, monthcalendar

I am doing a School Management System Project which is a desktop application using c#.net.In that My Module is Attendance of Students. I am Collecting a list of absent days of a student.

Now the Problem is to highlight the absent days of a student in a month calender in the Reports of Attendance.

For Ex, If the user select a student and Month, I will get a list of days for which he was absent. 
so, The student "ABC" absent for 3 days(8th, 16th,19th) in the January Month. So My requirement is to highlight these 3 days in Month Calender Control of C#.

Please Suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime[] absentDates = {myVacation1, myVacation2};
monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = absentDates;
```

Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9a9k6dd.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/monthcalendar) for more details about bold dates.

You cannot highlight dates by using the default properties. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MonthCalendar.aspx) is a project that does the highlighting.

Comment: Ya, I agree with your answer. But my job is to cross the absent days.

Comment: Check whether this helps. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/911e721a-7009-419a-aafa-dae39f48bd5c